# How to track writeObject() Progress

Tags: java, tracking, progress, objectoutputstream

I tried the Following:
But it didn't even print out a single number :/
the file is 700mb large an takes around ~ 15s

the 2nd class should hook into the outputstream if I understood it right
and I couldn't find a solution anywhere else

Problem: I'm unable to track the process of "writeObject()" - I'm trying to do a progressbar to show how much of the file is allready uploaded

```
public class Main {  
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  


        String file_name = "M:\\Config\\huge.avi";

        File file = new File(file_name);  
        System.out.println(file.getPath());
        if(file.exists()){
            Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 4112);  


            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());  
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());  

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);  

            MyCountingStream mcs = new MyCountingStream(oos);


            oos.writeObject(file.getName());  

            byte [] buffer = new byte[(int)file.length()];  
            Integer bytesRead = 0;  
            Timeline aftertickz = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(10), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    System.out.println(mcs.bytesWrittenSoFar());
                }
            }));
            aftertickz.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
            aftertickz.play();
            while ((bytesRead = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                oos.writeObject(bytesRead);  
                oos.flush();
                oos.writeObject(Arrays.copyOf(buffer, buffer.length));  
            }  

            oos.close();  
            ois.close();  
            mcs.close();
            fis.close();
            socket.close();
            System.exit(0);     
        }else{
            System.out.println("File doesn't exist");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }  
}  



public class MyCountingStream extends DataOutputStream {
    public MyCountingStream(OutputStream out) {
        super(out);
    }

    public int bytesWrittenSoFar() {
        return written;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please specify your problem

Comment: *may have forgotten it sry* It's on the top now

Answer (score 0):

You could just send the file as a stream of raw bytes instead of using writeObject() then track (number of bytes sent / file size in bytes) * 100 rounded to the nearest whole number.

Or.....
Take a look at:
[Getting Progress of ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366002/getting-progress-of-objectoutputstream-objectinputstream)

Comment: I've literally seached for 1 hour now and couldn't manage it.. could you give me an example for your "raw byte stream" ?

Comment: Rather than writing actual code, I'm gonna tell you what search will give you the concept. Search for something like "java track download progress".